# Variável "saida" foi definida mas nunca foi usada IAR System

Tags: c, variáveis

Estou fazendo um código para uma atividade do curso, porém quando vou compilar o código o programa IAR System me informa um aviso na variável saída dizendo que ela foi declarada porém nunca foi usada, não estou conseguindo retirar este aviso. Gostaria de uma ajuda o mais rápido possível pois tenho que entregar este código até o final do dia.

````
void main( void )
{
 // Stop watchdog timer to prevent time out reset
 WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;```
 
   P1DIR = P1DIR & 0x3F;  // Programar os bits 6 e 7 da porta 1 como entrada
   P1DIR = P1DIR | 0x0F; // Programar os bits 0 a 3 da porta 1 como saída
   const char Const_1 = 10, Const_2 = 9;
   char chave, saida;
       while(1)
       {
         chave = P1IN & 0xB0; // Ler chave
           if ( chave == 0)
             saida = Const_1 || Const_2;
         else if ( chave == 1)
           saida = Const_1 | Const_2;
         else if ( chave == 2)
           saida = !Const_1;
         else
           saida = ~Const_1;
       }
}
````

Comment: Você definiu a variável `saida` e atribuiu valores a ela com base em condições. Mas por quê? Usará esse valor em algum lugar?

Comment: Guilherme, seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Como está compilando o programa? Você pode retirar esses avisos ao omitir algumas flags, como `-Wall` por exemplo (se estiver usando o GCC). Apenas tenha certeza do que está fazendo, pois essas flags podem ser úteis no futuro.

Comment: Este é um programa de uma calculadora lógica, verificando permanentemente o estado da chave, e para cada estado da chave efetua uma operação lógica ou lógica bit a bit e essas operações devem ser realizadas entre as duas constantes: 10 e 9.

Comment: Ruan Montelo, como faz para omitir flags? Estou programando pelo IAR System.